# Como remplazar un salto de linea de un richTextBox por un espacio c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buen día... tengo un `richTextBox` en el cual ingreso un texto luego ese texto lo paso a un `string`, después ese mismo `string` lo pongo en un `textbox`. Pero cuando le asigno ese `string` al `textbox` los saltos de línea que he agregado con la tecla enter no aparecen y el texto sale junto.

[image]

este es el código del boton "Pasar texto"

```
string texto = richTextBox1.Text;
textBox1.Text = texto;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día, tienes que tener varias consideraciones, primero que todo el `TextBox` debe tener la propiedad `Multiline` en `true`.

```
textBox1.Multiline = true;
```

También puedes modificar propiedad desde el Design de Visual Studio.

Ahora bien, los saltos de linea son manejados diferentes en cada control, en el `RichTextBox` son manejados por `"\n"`, mientras que en los `TextBox` tienen la forma `"\r\n"`. Aquí te dejo el código de como resolver tu problema

```
string texto = richTextBox1.Text;
texto = texto.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
textBox1.Text = texto;
```

Comment: gracias... me ha servido

Comment: Un placer ayudarte.